# Retrieving Data from a dynamic WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, data-entry

I'm having some trouble with my WPF Form.

I have a list of objects, those objects have properties for Name, Value, IsRequired, Type (either bool, string or Datepicker).

So my list could have any number of objects and they could be either bool string etc.

I have created a custom control that propagates through this list and builds the form with the relevant controls such as CheckBox if its a bool and TextBox if its a string.

So far the code i have to generate this is like so, I have placed the controls in a grid for layout.

```
 private object GetCustomElement(DicomMetadataModel metadata)
    {
        Grid dynamicGrid = new Grid() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
        dynamicGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        // Margin order LTRB
        dynamicGrid.Margin = new Thickness(10, 3, 10, 3);

        // Grid Definitions
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col1.Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col2.Width = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star);
        RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
        gridRow1.Height = new GridLength(47);

        dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
        dynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);

        //Label
        var label = new Label()
        {
            FontSize = 15,
            MinHeight = 12,
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(_lblTextColor)
        };
        label.Content = new TextBlock() { TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow, Text = metadata.Label };

        Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
        dynamicGrid.Children.Add(label);

        if (metadata.Type == typeof(string) || metadata.Type == typeof(int))
        {
            //Textbox
            var textBox = new TextBox()
            {
                MinWidth = 150,
                MinHeight = 20,
                Padding = new Thickness(5),
                FontSize = 16,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(_lblTextColor),
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_tbBorderColor),
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(_tbBackgroundColor)
            };
            textBox.IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly;

            Grid.SetRow(textBox, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 1);

            dynamicGrid.Children.Add(textBox);

        }
        else if (metadata.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            //RadioButton
            var stack = new WrapPanel();

            var view = new Viewbox() { MaxWidth = 30, Margin = new Thickness(10) };
            var radioButton = new RadioButton()
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(_tbBackgroundColor),
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_tbBorderColor),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF7373"))
            };

            view.Child = radioButton;
            stack.Children.Add((UIElement)view);

            Grid.SetRow(stack, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(stack, 1);

            dynamicGrid.Children.Add(stack);
        }

        return dynamicGrid;
    }
```

This code is to create each element, this is recursively called in the following method

```
private void LoadViewerStudyInformation()
    {

        var dicomMetadata = DataContext as List<DicomMetadataModel>;
        if (dicomMetadata == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var metadata in dicomMetadata)
        {
            if (!metadata.IsVisible)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(count < 5)
            {
                Children.Add((UIElement)GetCustomElement(metadata));                    
                count++;
            }
            Margin = new Thickness(10);
            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        }

        // TODO build control, bind field to DataContext models
       // TODO how result of control is bound to DataContext model Result property
    }
```

This creates the the form as i would like it to appear on the screen.

I am having trouble now however hooking up the data entered and binding it to some model to store the information off.

I can hook up to the textbox TextChanged events but when it is fired there is not indication as to what property it should store to.

Will i need to create a new class say that has maybe a textbox and label property in it and call it like so , myClass.Textbox.Text etc.

MetaDataDicomModel here is like so

```
public class DicomMetadataModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to create something overly complicated because of a lack of understanding, if anyone could suggest the best way to do it i would be very grateful.

Comment: Just set The TextBox.Text to the property you need, but first set the DataContext of the TextBox, Read about DataContext as well. And because you are using code behind read about Binding in the code behind. HTH

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding. You can do with using a WPF `ItemsControl`, bound directly to your `List<DicomMetadataModel>`, much more easily.